# Raw PHP code showing below my footer on my website

Tags: php, html

I am having problems with my php code which shows itself under my footer. I tried everything by adding php in another file and include the php file in my code but also that isnt working. The funny part is when I copy the code and paste it under the php code one is showing under my footer and one is showing at the place where it should be.

```
<!-- LINK FOR TABLE CSS -->
<!-- LINK VOOR TABEL CSS -->                        
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/table.css">
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
// CONNECTIE MAKEN MET DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// SELECT TABLE NAMES FROM PERSON, ADDRESS AND CV WHERE address_id IS person_address and cv_id IS person_cv
// SELECTEER VAN TABEL PERSON, ADDRESS AND CV WAAR address_id  GELIJK IS AAN person_address EN cv_id AAN person_cv
$sql = "SELECT person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, 
                 person_email, person_phonenumber,  
                 address_street,address_housenumber, 
                 address_city,address_state,address_zipcode, cv_path
          FROM person 
            inner join address on address.address_id = person.person_address 
            inner join cv on cv.cv_id = person.person_cv";

// EXECUTE QUERY IF THE RESULT BIGGER IS THAN ZERO
// VOER QUERY UIT ALS RESULTAAT GROTER IS DAN NUL
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  
// ECHO A TABLE WITH VALUES 
// ECHO EEN TABEL MET ONDERSTAANDE WAARDES
echo "<form action='admin.php' method='post'>"; 
echo "<table border=0 align=right>
<tr>
<th>Voornaam</th>
<th>Achternaam</th>
<th>Straat</th>
<th>Huisnummer</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Stad</th>
<th>Provincie</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Mobiel</th>
<th>cv</th>
<th>delete</th>
</tr>";

// LOOP THROUGH THE RESULTS AND OUTPUT THE RESULTS FOR EACH ROW
// GA DOOR RESULTATEN EN LAAT DE RESULTEN PER RIJ ZIEN
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_firstname"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_lastname"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_street"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_housenumber"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_zipcode"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_city"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_state"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_email"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_phonenumber"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'] . "'>cv file</a></td>";
     echo "<td><a href='delete.php?person_id=" . $row['person_id'] . "'>delete</a></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</form>";
 }

// IF THERE IS ZERO RESULT ECHO THIS
// ALS WAARDE NUL IS LAAT DE ONDERSTAADE TEKST ZIEN
else {
    echo "<p id='Tekst'>Er zijn geen deelnemers in de database gevonden.</p>";
  }
  // CLOSE CONNECTION
  // SLUIT CONNECTIE
  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

[image: link2]
[image: link3]

The other thing I noticed... When I did echo all th one by one it did show the table on the right place with just one value from database... It also showed the other values BUT it didnt show it in the table

Comment: Add the code please. Leave the screenshots out unless necessary.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss a closing `</table>` tag before the closing `</form>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like uou didn t close the `<table>`